# Is my solution correct to the problem ? Memberwise and Custom Initializers

Tags: swift

Make a Height struct with two variable properties, heightInInches and heightInCentimeters. Both should be of type Double.

Create two custom initializers. One initializer will take a Double argument that represents height in inches. The other initializer will take a Double argument that represents height in centimeters. Each initializer should take the passed in value and use it to set the property that corresponds to the unit of measurement passed in. It should then set the other property by calculating the right value from the passed in value. Hint: 1 inch = 2.54 centimeters.

```
struct Height{
    var heightInInches :Double=0.0
    var heightInCentimeters :Double=0.0

    init(inches:Double) {
        heightInInches=inches * 2.54
    }
    init(centimeters:Double) {
        heightInCentimeters=centimeters/2.54

    }


}
let inch = Height(inches:65)
print(inch.heightInInches)

let centi=Height(centimeters:65)
print(centi.heightInCentimeters)
```

If you use the initializer for inches to pass in a height of 65, the initializer should set heightInInches to 65 and heightInCentimeters to 165.1.

Comment: I suggest you to move the conversion into `didSet{}` methods. The problem here is that after it gets initiaized, if you change `heightInInches` for instance, then `heightInCentimeters` wont change. This is fixed by implementing `didSet` : https://medium.com/the-andela-way/property-observers-didset-and-willset-in-swift-4-c3730f26b1e9

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense, if you supply the `inches` to calculate the result and apply it to the centimetres property rather then to the inches property?

Comment: Your current initializers should each be setting both properties. And it should set them correctly. Right now you do the math for the wrong properties.

Comment: BTW - when posting a question, you should word it as an actual question covering the actual issue you are having instead of quoting your homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Backup for a second and take each requirement in isolation

> One initializer will take a Double argument that represents height in inches. 
>   The other initializer will take a Double argument that represents height in centimeters.
>
> Each initializer should take the passed in value and use it to set the property that corresponds to the unit of measurement passed in.

Which might look something like...

```
init(inches:Double) {
    heightInInches = inches
}

init(centimeters:Double) {
    heightInCentimeters = centimeters
}
```

> It should then set the other property by calculating the right value from the passed in value. Hint: 1 inch = 2.54 centimeters.

Which might look more like this...

```
init(inches:Double) {
    heightInInches = inches
    heightInCentimeters = inches * 2.54
}
init(centimeters:Double) {
    heightInInches = centimeters / 2.54
    heightInCentimeters = centimeters
}
```

This then allows you to set the properties as `let` and avoid all the issues with a mutating `struct`

```
struct Height{
    let heightInInches: Double
    let heightInCentimeters: Double

    init(inches:Double) {
        heightInInches = inches
        heightInCentimeters = inches * 2.54
    }
    init(centimeters:Double) {
        heightInInches = centimeters / 2.54
        heightInCentimeters = centimeters

    }
}
```

which is a lesson best left for another day ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the conversion into `didSet{}` methods. The problem here is that after it gets initialized, if you change `heightInInches` for instance, then `heightInCentimeters` won't change.

```
struct Height{
    var heightInInches :Double {
        didSet {
            // called each time heightInInches changes
            heightInCentimeters = heightInInches / 2.54
        }
    }
    var heightInCentimeters :Double {
        didSet {
            // idem
            heightInInches = heightInCentimeters * 2.54
        }
    }

    init(inches:Double) {
        heightInInches = inches
        heightInCentimeters = inches / 2.54
    }
    init(centimeters:Double) {
        heightInCentimeters = centimeters
        heightInInches = centimeters * 2.54
    }
}
```

Note that `didSet` is not called via init methods. You have to duplicate this conversion or to place it in another function that will be call in the init **and** the didSet.